# Notations for random variable indepedence vs orthogonality

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

I used to use $X \perp Y$ to denote that $2$ random variables $(X,Y)$ are mutually independent or orthogonal. However, I have come to realize that r.v. independence and orthogonality are NOT equivalent.

Now my question is: how do we differentiate them in notations?

Comment: $X \perp Y$ is not a standard notation for either of the two concepts. So you have to understand it from the context.

Comment: I suppose $\sigma(X)\perp \sigma(Y)$ is an option

Comment: This symbol is often used: $\perp \! \! \perp$. See [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/03/27/conditional-independence-notation/).

Answer (score 3):

Both $\perp $ and $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ are used for independence as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Conditional_independence_of_random_variables), and context should make clear what the symbol is intended to mean.  However, as you note, $\perp $ is not really the best symbol for independence as it can be construed as denoting orthogonality (uncorrelatedness), which is weaker than independence.

In this sense, $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ is a much more fitting symbol for independence, not only because it is distinct from the typical symbol for orthogonality, but also because it suggests a much stronger notion than orthogonality.

Comment: Thanks! I recommend removing "(uncorrelatedness)" since uncorrelatedness is a special - not general - case of orthogonality (see [here](https://rinterested.github.io/statistics/independence_correlation_orthogonality.html)).

Comment: @peacefulzephyr Thanks for your comment.  However, the link you mention actually suggests different notions of orthogonality (including $E[XY]=0$ and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$...the latter is actually [fairly common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Statistics,_econometrics,_and_economics)), which is why I think it is *essential* to specify uncorrelatedness here to highlight the *particular* inner product we are working with.  Note that independence does not imply that $E[XY]=0$ but it does imply uncorrelatedness.